# Testing a controller API that refirects

Tags: nestjs

I have a controller in Nest.JS that redirects:

```js
    @Get('route/:value')
    async route(@Param('value') value: string) {
      const result = await this.someService.doSomethingWithValue(value);
      if (result) {
        return { url: 'http://example.com/success.html' };
      } else {
        return { url: 'http://example.com/fail.html' };
      }
    }
```

How can I test in controller.spec.ts the correct redirect response?
i.e.:

```js
describe('test', () => {
    it('should show success page', async() => {
      service.doSomethingWithValue = jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve(true));
      expect(controller.route('value')).toBe(?????);
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be exactly what you expect it to be. You are returning values, it should be those values, right? Actually those objects, so you should use `toEqual` instead of `toBe`. In this case, you're returning `true` so you should have `expect(controller.route('value')).toEqual({ url: 'http://example.com/success.html' })`. Start using return types on everything you can, it'll help you in the long run.

Comment: Validated it works with a slight change:
`const response = await controller.route('value');
expect(response).toEqual({ url: 'http://example.com/success.html'});`